# Chrome browser losing certificate on startup linux

Tags: google-chrome, certificates

Every time I restart Linux, I lose the certificate of the project that I installed through the Chrome browser. What should I do to save this permanently, without losing it?

The certificate was generated to run in a local project, it was installed by the browser, within the security area in the authorities tab.
The problem that seems to happen is that Chrome tends to reset its default settings

- **Chrome:** version 119.0.6045.199 (Oficial version) unknown 64 bits
- **Linux:**
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
  Release:    23.04
  Codename:   lunar
  6.2.0-39-generic

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I think other users here may find more information helpful and this may help you get more people to consider your question. More information like, **where and how did you generate/create and save the certificate** (if you did save the certificate), **how did you discover and what indicates to you that the certificate is missing** (exact error messages are extremely helpful here — copied and pasted into your question, of course). Also, **what solutions have you considered or tried so far?**